# A problem with sub/super-solution methods in PDEs book by Evans

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am studying in a (second edition) Partial Differential Equations book by Evans. I am reading the sub/super-solution method in page 543.

Everything is fine and clear to me. However, there is one thing I think it is unacceptable. That is giving the definitions of sub-solution and super-solution without proving their existence. What will happen if they do not exist? I guess the method must be failed. Moreover, I am also reading some papers using this method, and those authors only give the definitions without proving the existence.

I may miss any chapter of the book that shows the existence of sub/super-solution. But please anyone help me give explanation or share some pdfs that have further knowledge of sub/super-solution method, and more especially, the existence of sub/super-solution.

So sorry but I must state that this method is not true until I can read some documents about the existence. I actually do not mean anything negative, but I still cannot get this above problem.

Anyway, thank you for your help and sorry if I do not understand, and ask something straightforward to you.

Comment: In the future, I recommend writing the whole problem out instead of pointing to an external reference, so that people without the material can help you. Reading through it, it seems to concern the problem $-\Delta u = f(u)$. The book doesn't claim that super/subsolutions always exist, it simply says that if you can find some, then a solution necessarily exists too. This is very useful because, depending on the $f$, it is often much easier to find super/subsolutions than actual solutions directly.